# "... die, die die Erde zugrunde gerichtet haben ..."

Tags: grammar-identification

> Wie können wir hoffen, dass **die, die die** Erde zugrunde gerichtet
> haben, auf uns hören?

Eine Frage zu diesen drei *die*.

Das zweite *die* ist das Relativpronomen, das den Relativsatz einleitet.

Das dritte *die* ist der Artikel von *Erde*.

Ist das erste *die* das Demonstrativpronomen (*diejenigen, die* …) oder der Artikel zum weggelassenen Wort *Menschen/Leute*?

Answer (score 8):

In der klassischen Terminologie ist das erste - betonte - *die* ein Demonstrativpronomen. Es verweist kataphorisch auf die Bestimmung im nachfolgenden Relativsatz. Die Betonung weist schon darauf hin, dass es sich gerade *nicht* um ein Weglassungsprodukt handelt. Dies wäre im Übrigen auch strukturell nicht möglich, weil ein einzelnes (naturgemäß begleitendes) Artikelwort generell kein taugliches Tilgungsprodukt ist.

(Kleine sprachgeschichtliche Notiz: Das Demonstrativpronomen *der, die, das* ist, nebenbei bemerkt, auch historisch nicht das Ergebnis einer solchen Weglassung. Im Althochdeutschen entstand der bestimmte Artikel aus dem Demonstrativpronomen *dër, diu, daʒ*, nicht umgekehrt.)

Das zweite und dritte *die* haben Sie richtig identifiziert.

Comment: Ich würde etwas leichter verdauliche Formulierungen begrüßen; diese Antwort ist für einen Nichtmuttersprachler schon etwas heftig.

Comment: @johnl: Die Antwort ist absolut verständlich formuliert, vielen Dank! =)

Answer (score 7):

Zwei dieser drei Wörter kann man ohne Veränderung der Bedeutung durch Synonyme ersetzen:

> Wie können wir hoffen, dass **jene, welche die** Erde zugrunde gerichtet haben, auf uns hören?

- Die Ersetzung von *»die«* durch *»jene«* klappt nur bei Demonstrativpronomen, weil *jener/jene/jenes* ein reines Demonstrativpronomen ist.
- Die Ersetzung von *»die«* durch *»welche«* klappt nur bei Relativpronomen. Das Wort *welcher/welche/welches* kann drei verschiedenen Wortarten angehören:

  - Interrogativpronomen

    > **Welche** Flasche ist leer?
  - Relativpronomen

    > Die Flasche, **welche** leer ist, liegt im Müll.
  - Indefinitpronomen

    > Wenn du Flaschen suchst: Auf dem Tisch stehen **welche.**

  Von diesen drei Wortarten stimmt nur die Wortart *Relativpronomen* mit einer Wortart überein, die das Wort *»die«* annehmen kann (bestimmter Artikel, Relativpronomen, Demonstrativpronomen, Personalpronomen)

Wenn man will, kann man sogar das dritte *»die«* durch ein anderes Wort ersetzten, dadurch entsteht aber eine Veränderung der Bedeutung des Satzes:

> Wie können wir hoffen, dass jene, welche **eine** Erde zugrunde gerichtet haben, auf uns hören?

Hier wurde der bestimmte Artikel durch einen unbestimmten Artikel ersetzt. Das geht natürlich nur, wenn *»die«* ein Artikel ist.

Wenn man das macht, verschwindet aber die ursprüngliche Bedeutung, die besagt, dass es nur eine Erde gibt. Mit dem unbestimmten Artikel wird ausgesagt, dass es mehrere Erden gibt. Auf der Ebene der Grammatik (rein syntaktisch, ohne Beachtung der Semantik) ist die Ersetzung aber dennoch möglich und als Nachweis dafür geeignet, dass ein Artikel vorliegt.